# How do I get Content of wordpress with .net api?

Tags: c#, .net, wordpress, api

I am using [joeblogs](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs) as wordpress api for .net

I use that code to get info about my blog

```
    WordPressWrapper wrapper = new WordPressWrapper("http://www.xxxx.org/xmlrpc.php", "xxx", "yyyyy");
  var post = new Post()
           {
               Body = "This is a test body",
               Categories = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" },
               Tags = new string[] { "tag one", "another tag", "one more" },
               Title = "Test post "                         
           };

           int idsi= wrapper.NewPost(post, true);
          IEnumerable<Post> recentPosts = wrapper.GetRecentPosts(100);
           foreach (Post recentPost in recentPosts)
           {

           }

           var userBlogs = wrapper.GetUserBlogs();
           var tags = wrapper.GetTags();
           var categories = wrapper.GetCategories();

           var authors = wrapper.GetAuthors();
```

There is not problem on that code. But For example I want to get content of another wordpress website.. such as this website: http://en.blog.wordpress.com/ and topic 
http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/new-themes-babylog-and-delicacy/

It calls as feeding. and here is feeding link of this topic

http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/new-themes-babylog-and-delicacy/feed/

But it doesnt have content of the topic. I can do it with blogger api because it supports feeding content. How can I get content of a topic with that api for .net ?

p.s.: I dont want to use rest of that api.

Answer (score 1):

The JoeBlogs wrapper is to support operations allowable by the XML RPC Api (either metaweblog or wordpress)

You need to handle RSS feeds to support the URL you gave.
See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87278/what-is-the-best-net-library-to-handle-feeds-atomrss

Failing that, you could instantiate a new WordpressWrapper for the other site?

Source: I'm the author of [JoeBlogs](http://github.com/alexjamesbrown/joeblogs)